# Modify XML File with SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I'm currently trying to generate a set of models (specified via XML). In order to achieve this, I need to change a single attribute inside the file and save it under a new file name.

The XML File looks like this:

```
(...)
<place id="P19" initialMarking="0" invariant="&lt; inf" markingOffsetX="0.0" markingOffsetY="0.0" name="P19" nameOffsetX="-5.0" nameOffsetY="35.0" positionX="615.0" positionY="375.0"/>
<place id="P20" initialMarking="0" invariant="&lt; inf" markingOffsetX="0.0" markingOffsetY="0.0" name="P20" nameOffsetX="-5.0" nameOffsetY="35.0" positionX="375.0" positionY="225.0"/>
(...)
```

What needs changing is the value of initialMarking to values from 2 through 999.

Here is what I have so far:
This is where I get the list of files to change and pass them to the parser

```
public void parse(String dir){
        getFiles(dir);

        try {
            XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

            for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileList[i]);
                InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
                xmlReader.setContentHandler(new ModelContentHandler());
                xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
            }
(...)
```

This is where I'm searching for the element I need to change:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals("place") && atts.getValue(0).equals("P14") && atts.getValue(1).equals("2")){
            System.out.println("Initial Marking of " + atts.getValue(0) + " is: " + atts.getValue(1) + "\n");
            while(currentTokens <= Configuration.MAX_TOKENS){
                System.out.println("Setting initial Tokens to: " + currentTokens);

            }
        }
    }
```

Now, instead of printing out "Setting..." I'd like to change the according value and just save the whole file under some new name like "Model_X_Y_Token.xml".

Seems like a fairly simple thing to do, but I've never used SAX before and looking at the JavaDoc, I can't even find a place to start.
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: is SAX a requirement? DOM would be much easier to code with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best approaches here is to use [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/download.html).I don't exactly get the big picture of what you're trying to do, but I understand the result you want to get. Note that you will also need jaxen for this.

Step 1 : read the file into an xml doxument

```
for(int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){
        Document doc = new SAXReader().read(fileList[i]);
    }
```

Step 2 : parse the elements you need. For this you need to know a bit of xpath. //*/place will fetch all the place elements. //*/place[@id="P14"] will fetch only one place element.

```
Element place14 = (Element) doc.selectSingleNode("//*/place[@id="p14" and   initialMarking="2"]");
```

Step 3 : change the attributes of the element

plac14.attribute("attributename").setValue("attributeValue");

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have some problems implementing your suggestion.
1. The XPath-statement seems wrong. The Element-object is always empty. I changed the String to `//place[@id="P14"] | //place[@initialMarking="2"]` after looking into XPath.

Using http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm it correctly identified the node in my document. The method selectSingleNode does not and again, produces an Element-object containing "null".

Also, after changing the Attribute, how can I save the document under a new name? The Document-object doesn't have a method for it.

Comment: To narrow it down, I modified the XPath-statement to only select a node that has `"//place[@initialMarking=\'2\']"`. The selectSingleNode also returns just "null" in this case.

Comment: After further investigations, this seems to be a namespace-problem. There is a line `xmlns="http://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/top/pnml/ptNetb"` in my XML-file. If I remove this, it is working. Unfortunately, I have to make it work WITH the namespace.

Comment: Alright, I got it now. I should not have removed the `//*` in front of the XPath. Thank you, YashGhatti!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way possible is with [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net) as it is the only API that does something called incremental update...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class changeAttrVal {
    public  static  void main(String s[]) throws VTDException,java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,java.io.IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/*/place[@id=\"p14\" and   @initialMarking=\"2\"]/@initialMarking");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.updateToken(i+1, "499");// change initial marking from 2 to 499
        }
        xm.output("new.xml"); // output to a new document called new.xml
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just tried vtd-xml and I'm running into some problems. With your code example, the Input-file gets only saved as it is, under the name "new.xml". The modifications aren't working.

Also, I modified your example, since I want a new File for every change of "initialMarking", so I get something like "new 2 tokens.xml", "new 3 tokens.xml" and so on. So I moved the xm.output into the while-loop as: xm.output("new " + i + ".xml");. This isn't working at all, no files are saved.

Comment: the output is identical with inplut because the xpath is not evaluating to anything... so there is no change... what would be the right xpath expression for your app loigc?

Comment: btw, dom4j is a dog, here is a paper on that subject http://sdiwc.net/digital-library/web-admin/upload-pdf/00000466.pdf